# GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 says BGRA is cool, so what's the deal?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, camera, avfoundation, rgba

This is another take on a question which has no responses. The iPhone has the extension GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, which is supposed to allow me to use BGRA as the internal format of glTexImage2d.

I have only BGRA data, as that's the only thing I can get from the camera (other than YUV which I'm not ready to deal with).

How can I use BGRA with `glReadPixels`? Anything I try gives me a black screen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/2.0/docs/man/glReadPixels.xml), `glReadPixels()` only supports RGBA as the format to read back from your FBO.  I believe the extension you quote there only allows for BGRA pixel format data to be provided to your texture, not that you can read back an FBO in BGRA format.

As Ben suggests, you can just swizzle the color components in your fragment shader if you need to have the end result be BGRA.

Comment: For some reason I had been looking at non-ES docs (in which BGRA is supported). BGRA (or YUV) is the only format allowed to/from the camera (such as supplying an assetwriter)...it's allowed for a texture, but then it's not allowed as a store or to be read back from. Confusing! Thanks for clearing it up, Brad. Now I'd like to figure out how to pass a full YpCbCr 4:2:0 frame to opengl...

Comment: @akaru - Me too.  On the Mac, Apple has an extension that lets you use the GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE color format for YUV 4:2:2 textures, but unfortunately that's missing on the iPhone.

Comment: I can only get the first plane (greyscale) by glTexImage2d'ing with RGBA. GL_LUMINANCE gives me an error, though docs say it's supported. Sigh.

Comment: I'm seeing http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/APPLE/rgb_422.txt for support of 4:2:2 textures, but not 4:2:0 which is strange don't you think?

Comment: @akaru - Yes, I saw that recently too and couldn't quite figure out what to use it for.  They added it for a reason, though, so there must be a way to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check for OpenGL errors after creating and loading the texture?

Did you bind the texture?

Did you enable texture mapping with `glEnable`?

Did you specify texture coordinates for each vertex of your polygon?

Comment: Errors, yes. Bind, yes. glEnable, no. Textures, yes. I should clarify, screen output is correct. It is with glReadPixels that my problem lies. I can glTexImage2d a BGRA frame, if I setup my FBO with RGBA as the internal format. So, due to my setup, I can blit to screen fine, but using glReadPixels I get a black frame when setting it to BGRA, while RGBA gives me inverted colors (since it's actually stored as BGRA!).

Comment: @akaru: You should need either `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` or a fragment shader running.  Did you call `glFlush()` before `glReadPixels`, to make sure rendering occurs before capture?  Where is `glReadPixels` being called in relation to `SwapBuffers`? (or whatever it's named on iPhone, maybe `glXSwapBuffers`).

Comment: @akaru: Also, are you trying to read from the screen or from the FBO?

Comment: I'm using a fragment shader to blit to screen. I'm doing glReadPixels from the FBO. I haven't tried glFlush(), I thought glReadPixels would force the flush. As for swapBuffers(), I didn't know it was available on the iPhone. Note, however, that I can get everything to work if I'm ok with the colors being inverted. It's just that I think I should be able to keep BGRA all around but cannot. See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086863/bgra-on-iphone-glteximage2d-and-glreadpixels. BTW thanks for your help, you're the only one to chime in on an issue that I've been working on for days!

Comment: @akaru: Since you've got shader capability, how about telling opengl it's RGBA and using the shader to swizzle the components?  Something along the lines of `out_Color.xyzw = in_Color.zyxw;`

Comment: did you set glReadBuffer() properly?

Comment: @ben, I've considered using a shader, I just don't get why I would need to. If BGRA is supported, well, it should just work, right?

Comment: @kvark, no glReadBuffer() in es2 I don't think.

Comment: @akaru: Didn't you just say you're already using a shader?  The swizzle should occur basically for free as you apply the texture.  I agree that yeah just changing the pixel format shouldn't make your data completely disappear, but an easy workaround is almost as good, isn't it?